# A tag label não deixa quebrar linha facilmente dentro dela

Tags: html, css

Preciso de ajudar para descobrir como "quebrar linha" `dentro` da tag label. 
Por exemplo: tenho um label de 200px e todo nome que estiver dentro da tag label maior que 200px, deverá quebrar linha e passar para a linha abaixo, empurrando assim os demais labels para baixo.

Veja como estou tentando fazer, mas não está dando certo:

```
Veja no trecho de código
```

O texto deveria aparecer até mais ou menos a palavra libero e passar para a linha abaixo, mas não está "quebrando". 
**Não estou usando nenhum outro código além do estilo que estou demonstrando na própria tag label.**

```html
<fieldset style='position:relative;width:100%;max-width:600px;min-width:305px;text-align:left;border:1px solid rgba(121,138,151,0.5);border-radius:3px;padding:0 5px 10px 5px;'>
<legend>Programa social</legend>

<legend style='position:absolute;top:-1px;right:5px;background:#fff;'>
<div onclick='modalSocial();'>Incluir Programa</div>
</legend>

<div style='position:relative;margin:0 0 20px 5px;'>Clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre um Programa Social para ler a descrição</div>

<div style='position:relative;margin:5px 0;'>

<input type='checkbox' id='chpsa' name='psoc[]' value='xxxxx'>
<label for='chpsa' style='position:absolute;left:0;'></label>
<label for='chpsa' style='position:relative;width:200px;word-break:break-word;overflow:hidden;'>
Lorem ipsum ante mi vel sagittis libero aliquam quisque praesent aliquet suspendisse etiam praesent, senectus aenean sapien mi dapibus sit aptent eu consequat pellentesque est.
</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='chpsb' name='psoc[]' value='xxxxx'>
<label for='chpsb' style='position:absolute;left:0;'></label>
<label for='chpsb' style='position:relative;width:200px;word-break:break-word;overflow:hidden;'>
Lorem ipsum ante mi vel sagittis libero aliquam quisque praesent aliquet suspendisse etiam praesent, senectus aenean sapien mi dapibus sit aptent eu consequat pellentesque est.
</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='chpsc' name='psoc[]' value='xxxxx'>
<label for='chpsc' style='position:absolute;left:0;'></label>
<label for='chpsc' style='position:relative;width:200px;word-break:break-word;overflow:hidden;'>
Lorem ipsum ante mi vel sagittis libero aliquam quisque praesent aliquet suspendisse etiam praesent, senectus aenean sapien mi dapibus sit aptent eu consequat pellentesque est.
</label>

</div>
</fieldset>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`Sam` 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`Felipe` [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como eu disse na minha pergunta (em negrito): não estou usando! e o snippet realmente altera mesmo!

Comment: OK obrigado @Sam... coloquei do jeito que está e retirei o print.... "chupa essa manga" rs

Comment: Já tentei assim (display:inline-block), mas não deu @Sam... e se eu não colocar o overflow:hidden, o label rompe a linha do fieldset.

Comment: Pois é @Sam... vou postar a imagem do projeto para vc ver o que acontece... Note que o `Programa de Fomento` é cortado e não quebra linha..... e se eu retirar o overflow, ele completa tudo numa linha só

Comment: Sim @Sam! Duas colunas pois a DIV que comporta os checkboxes vai se repetir de acordo com a consulta do mysql e está com style display:inline-block... são muitos programas sociais, muitos mesmo, por isso a necessidade da coluna... veja a segunda imagem com o mesmo código que usei aqui no snippet. O label (com display:inline-block) não deixa quebrar linha de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Meu patrãozinho, sem poder reproduzir o código e sem saber o que vc quer fazer (até agora eu não entendi), fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Vou continuar pesquisando... valeu @Sam, vc é muito gentil!

Comment: Blz... só não use overflow que não tem nada a ver com quebra de linha. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos @Sam e @Felipe Maia, agradeço imensamente pelas dicas que me deram ao **resolverem** meu problema... Tudo o que vocês disseram faz sentido e está correto. Que Deus lhes abençoe por isso!

**Resolvi adicionando um estilo diretamente nos labels que estão dentro do meu fieldset:**

`.pro-social-label label { white-space:normal;word-break:break-word; }`

Nenhum outro label do projeto foi desconfigurado e somente os labels dos programas sociais foram alterados... Vejam a imagem (ainda estou reformulando. rsrs)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, você tenta usar um comportamento em uma etiqueta `label` que não vai funcionar como você espera porque não definiu como deve ser sua exibição enquanto bloco. Trocar `label` por `div` pode funcionar, mas vai perder a funcionalidade do atributo `for`. Mas usar duas label's foge um pouco do objetivo, uma vez que um `label` deve ser associada a outro elemento através do `for`. De acordo com a documentação:

> *The <label> element represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the <label> element’s labeled control, either using the `for` attribute, or by putting the form control inside the <label> element itself. [HTML 5.3]*

Mas o que você espera pode ser feito assim:

```css
 * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            padding: 2rem;
        }
        fieldset {
            position:relative;
            width:100%;max-width:600px;
            min-width:305px;
            text-align:left;
            border:1px solid rgba(121,138,151,0.5);
            border-radius:3px;
            padding:0 5px 10px 5px;
        }
        .custom-content {
            position:relative;
            margin:5px 0;
        }
        legend {
            background:#ffffff;
            padding: 0.25rem;
        }
        .legend-right {
            position:absolute;
            top:-1px;
            right:5px;
            background:#ffffff;
            padding: 0.25rem;
        }
        .custom-label {
            display: inline-block;
            position:relative;
            width:200px;
            word-break:break-word;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .custom-label-inline-block {
            display: inline-block;
            position:relative;
            width:200px;
            word-break:break-word;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
        .program-action {
            position:relative;
            margin:20px 5px;
        }
        .label-chps {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

```html
<fieldset>
        <legend>Programa social</legend>
                
        <div class="legend-right">
            <div onclick='modalSocial();'>Incluir Programa</div>        
        </div>

        <div class="program-action">Clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre um Programa Social para ler a descrição</div>
        
        <div class="custom-content">
            <label for='chpsa' class="label-chps">
                <input type='checkbox' id='chpsa' name='psoc[]' value='xxxxx'>
            </label>
            <div data-for="chpsa" class="custom-label">
                Lorem ipsum ante mi vel sagittis libero aliquam quisque praesent aliquet suspendisse etiam praesent, senectus aenean sapien mi dapibus sit aptent eu consequat pellentesque est.
            </div>
            <br>
            <label for="chpsb" class="label-chps">
                <input type='checkbox' id='chpsb' name='psoc[]' value='xxxxx'>
            </label>
            <label for="chpsb"  class="custom-label-inline-block">
                Lorem ipsum ante mi vel sagittis libero aliquam quisque praesent aliquet suspendisse etiam praesent, senectus aenean sapien mi dapibus sit aptent eu consequat pellentesque est.
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for='chpsc' class="label-chps">
                <input type='checkbox' id='chpsc' name='psoc[]' value='xxxxx'>
            </label>
            <div  class="custom-label">
                Lorem ipsum ante mi vel sagittis libero aliquam quisque praesent aliquet suspendisse etiam praesent, senectus aenean sapien mi dapibus sit aptent eu consequat pellentesque est.
            </div>        
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Na cor azul aqua, a `label` e as demais são elementos `div`.

Como você pode ver, adicionei um `display: inline-block` para fazer o bloco se ajustar de acordo com o tamanho do container. Se a largura for suficiente ele permanece em linha, se não, o último elemento bloco vai pra linha debaixo (caso haja mais de um ajustado como `inline-block`.

*Nota: Talvez o objetivo de usar CSS1 seja simplificar o código para uso aqui, mas, caso contrário, recomendo que use CSS2+. Além de deixar mais legível, vai economizar tempo e esforço.*

Referências:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-label-element
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-label-element

Comment: Não pode ser div @Felipe Maia, pois senão o click não funfa... não deu certo, mas agradeço

Comment: Acho que você nem sequer testou ou leu o código.

Comment: claro que sim... vou postar a imagem procê... É exatamente o que vc fez... não mudei uma vírgula... no snippet fica diferente mesmo..

Comment: A parte destacada em azul é um label, se você clicar no texto verá que a caixa de seleção é marcada. A quebra de texto ocorre normalmente, bem como é definida pela largura de 200px, o que não ocorre se você não atribuir um display.

Comment: Pois é @Felipe Maia!... Meu problema é com a quebra de linha no label... Veja a parte destacada em azul na imagem que postei com o seu código... não quebra de jeito nenhum

Comment: O código que fiz está livre de interferência de outra estilização do css. Teste isolado, só esse trecho.

Comment: Amigo @Felipe Maia, pode um estilo interferir em outro mesmo estando antes da estilização atual?